# Track changes in my linq2sql datamodel without having entities mapped to DB tables

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to use linq-to-sql, and this is all very new to me.

I am creating objects, that doens't translate to actual tables, in my database. In essence, I have some objects, that get values from 3 different tables, and I select them with stored procedures.
It works great.

However, when I need to submit my changes, I assume `SubmitChanges()` will not work, and I will need to make my own save functionality.

But how do I see what have actually changed? If I call `GetChangeSet()` on my datacontext, it says nothing has changed, even though the model has been changed.

Do I need to track the changes manually? If so, are there any tricks or practices I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinQ to Sql tracks that changes via auto-generated code. You can see it by hitting F12 on linq-to-sql generated object types.

Also, you could study it and make your objects to save changes inside datacontext (which is also a unit of work) the way the generator does.

Comment: The objects/entities are not auto generated. I made them, and set them as return objects, for the stored procedures/data functions I have in my datacontext.

Comment: @Nicolai so create some auto-generated entities and look how they implement the item change detection logic.